# How to pass variable between microfront end and parent container?

Tags: angular-elements, micro-frontend

I am trying to create an angular element microfrontend. This MF would be used in .net MVC apps.
The MF would be converted as a javascript file CDN to be consumed into parent app.

My question is how should I pass variable from .net MVC app to my microfrontend.